# prevent form from refreshing on submit - Ajax Call Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am working on a search form. This form takes two values `The job title` and `Location`. And on the basis of these keywords it crawls the data from web. On submitting the form, the form get refreshed. So for that reason I put `event.preventDefault()` on form submit. But the problem is in the URL the form values does not appear.

What I want is to get the URL as well, and to stop the page from getting refresh as well.

The form send the value through `GET` method. the action attribute is `index.php` which is the page itself.

**What I have done so far :**

```js
<form method="GET" action="index.php" id="search-form">
   <input type="text" placeholder="Job Title" class="job-search-inp job-title-inp" autocomplete="off" name="job_title" required>
   <input type="text" placeholder="Job Place" class="job-search-inp job-type-inp" autocomplete="off" name="job_loc" required>
   <button  type="submit" id="submit_btn"> <i class="fa fa-search"></i> </button>
</form>
```

**Ajax Request in the same index.php page:**

```js
$("body").on("submit", "#search-form", function(e) {

  var _e = e.target;

  console.log($(_e).serialize());
  $("#submit_btn i").hide();
  $("#submit_btn").html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif">');

  $http({
    method: "GET",
    url: "crawler3.php",
    data: $(_e).serialize() + "&start=0&crawl=true",
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
  }).then(function(res) {
    $("#submit_btn").html('<i class="fa fa-search"></i>');
    console.log(res.data);
  })
})
```

> This is how I want the URL to look : `http://localhost.com/Fiverr/Job%20Crawler/index.php?job_title=web&job_loc=pakistan`.
>   As the results of will be displayed on the same `index.php` page, I do not want the page to be refreshed.

Comment: You included the tags `javascript,jquery,html` and `ajax` while your index file is `index.php`. Is that an error perhaps?

Comment: @FDavidov the question is related to all, so thats why

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by adding a simple two lines of code :

```js
window.history.pushState('index.php',
  'title',
  window.location.pathname + '?' + $(_e).serialize()
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add return false within on submit.

```
$("body").on("submit", "#search-form", function(e) {
...
...

 $http({
   method: "GET",
   url: "crawler3.php",
   data: $(_e).serialize() + "&start=0&crawl=true",
   headers: {
   'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  }
 }).then(function(res) {
   $("#submit_btn").html('<i class="fa fa-search"></i>');
   console.log(res.data);
 })

 return false;

})
```